# PyGTK gtk.gdk.Pixbuf.copy_area erroneously copying alpha bits

Tags: python, transparency, pygtk, gdkpixbuf, pixbuf

Here is a picture illustrating the issue I am having:

[image]

This picture was created with the following:

```
cube.copy_area(0, 0, cube.get_width(), cube.get_height(), self.canvas, o2i[0], o2i[1])
```

where `cube` and `canvas` are of the type `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf`.  `o2i` is simply a tuple containing the results of an isometric placement function that draws back to front.

The issue I'm having, as I hope is evident, is that in copying `cube`, which has an alpha channel, to `canvas`, the `copy_area()` function is also setting the bits in the destination Pixbuf to 0 alpha.  This makes sense if `copy_area()` really just copies one buffer stream into another at an offset, but is clearly not my intent.  Is there any way to copy the contents of one Pixbuf into another, using the source Pixbuf's alpha channel as a copy mask?

<sub>For reference, [here is PyGTK's documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--copy-area) for `copy_area()`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is composite(). It's somewhat inconvenient to use because it handles the coordinates differently, but something like this should make it work exactly like copy_area:

```
def copy_area_composite(source_buf, source_x, source_y, width, height, dest_buf, dest_x, dest_y):
    source_buf.composite(dest_buf, dest_x, dest_y, width, height, dest_x-src_x, dest_y-rect_y, 1, 1, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.NEAREST, 255)
```